# Website with Version number of a Testflight App

Tags: ios, testflight

Can I see the Data of the Testflight App via a website.

For Example Version Number and Changelog.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
Your server code should connect to the following service:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi

The specific API call for your need is:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/list_apps

Comment: Thank you for the Answer. I forgot to mention that I'm not the Owner of the App.Is there also a way if i'm a Betatester and just have the Testflight invite Link ?